# Where the $1/2!$ term comes from in the symmetry factor for Feynman diagram?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, feynman-diagrams

I'm trying to understand the symmetry factor for this diagram:

[image]

The combinatorial factors make sense to me, and the two vertices in $\phi^4$ theory give two $1/4!$ terms. I wonder how the $1/2!$ term comes from the 2nd order correction?

Comment: Yes, that’s it.

Answer (score 1):

It actually comes from the expansion of the exponential in terms of the coupling constant $\frac{1}{n!}$